# Add content of XML file to another one using bash script

Tags: bash, xml

I have two XML file first one `~/tmp/test.xml` second one `/data/myuser/.mycontent/mytest.xml` I want to add all of the content on the first XML file to line 35 in the second one. I tried the following but with no luck

```
sed -n '35,~/tmp/test.xml`' /data/myuser/.mycontent/mytest.xml

(cat /data/myuser/.mycontent/mytest.xml; echo) | sed '35r ~/tmp/test.xml'

ed -s ~/tmp/test.xml <<< $'35r /data/myuser/.mycontent/mytest.xml\nw'
```

Line 33 from second XML file line 34 is empty

```
#the following tags contain employee location
```

XML tag in the first XML file

```
<Location "/mylocation">
    first Address
    second Address

    Mylocation "XX/XX/XX/XX"
    Myphone "XXXXXXX"
</Location>
```

What did I do wrong, please advise .

**Edit 1**

first XML `~/tmp/test.xml` file contain only

```
<Location "/mylocation">
    first Address
    second Address

    Mylocation "XX/XX/XX/XX"
    Myphone "XXXXXXX"
</Location>
```

second XML `/data/myuser/.mycontent/mytest.xml` contain:

```
NameVirtualHost *:XXXX
<VirtualHost  *:XXXX>

    ServerName AAAAAAAA

# Manager comment 1
# Manager comment 2
# Manager comment 3
#
DocumentRoot "/data/myuser/.mycontent/"

# support email xxxxx@yyyyy.com
# started at 2010
<employee /*>
        AllowOverride None
</employee>

<Location "/">
        mylocation
        Deny from all
</Location>

<Location "/icons/">
#        employee info
        my employee info
        Allow from all
</Location>

DavLockDB /tmp/${APACHE_HOSTNAME}.DavLock
DAVMinTimeout 5000
LimitXMLRequestBody 0

# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.

## I need to add new tags here ##
<Location "/employee1">
    first Address
    second Address

    Mylocation "XX/XX/XX/XX"
    Myphone "XXXXXXX"
</Location>

<Location "/employee2">
    first Address
    second Address

    Mylocation "XX/XX/XX/XX"
    Myphone "XXXXXXX"
</Location>
## more tags same as above
## then manager comment
```

**Edit 2**
second file `/data/myuser/.mycontent/mytest.xml` should be like:

```
 NameVirtualHost *:XXXX
    <VirtualHost  *:XXXX>

        ServerName AAAAAAAA

    # Manager comment 1
    # Manager comment 2
    # Manager comment 3
    #
    DocumentRoot "/data/myuser/.mycontent/"

    # support email xxxxx@yyyyy.com
    # started at 2010
    <employee /*>
            AllowOverride None
    </employee>

    <Location "/">
            mylocation
            Deny from all
    </Location>

    <Location "/icons/">
    #        employee info
            my employee info
            Allow from all
    </Location>

    DavLockDB /tmp/${APACHE_HOSTNAME}.DavLock
    DAVMinTimeout 5000
    LimitXMLRequestBody 0

    # This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.

    ## I need to add new tags here ##
  ## this tag from first file   
  <Location "/mylocation">
        first Address
        second Address

        Mylocation "XX/XX/XX/XX"
        Myphone "XXXXXXX"
    </Location>

  ## edit end

    <Location "/employee1">
        first Address
        second Address

        Mylocation "XX/XX/XX/XX"
        Myphone "XXXXXXX"
    </Location>

    <Location "/employee2">
        first Address
        second Address

        Mylocation "XX/XX/XX/XX"
        Myphone "XXXXXXX"
    </Location>
    ## more tags same as above
    ## then manager comment
```

Note: `## this tag from first file` and `## edit end` to specify merge location location

Comment: Can you give XML samples from both files - the core problem is, XML isn't plain text, and if you treat it as if it is, you create brittle code. Using a parser is the answer - I can give you an example if you can post your XML. (And indicate which _tag_ you want to insert your content into)

Comment: @Sobrique I added content of file one and some of the content of file two

Comment: That isn't XML,  which changes the answer

Comment: @Sobrique the page is extension XML thats why I added its XML page. sorry if I added wrong info.

Comment: i dont understand this question - you want all of the content in file one on line 35 of file 2? so you want it flattened? Or you want all of the content *prepended* to line 35? Or you want it *appended*? Or do you want it *joined* such that the content from the first line of file 1 is appended to the tail of line 35 and all of the rest of lines in file1 then follow?

Comment: @mikeserv I edited the question again by adding edit 2, in edit 1 I added the content of both files, in edit 2 how 2nd file `/data/myuser/.mycontent/mytest.xml` should contain after merging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so this isn't XML inserting into XML like I thought - if it was, the answer would be 'use a parser'. However it's not, you're just merging one text file into another.

So I would break out the `perl` as I so often do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open ( my $insert, '<', '~/tmp/test.xml' ) or die $!;
open ( my $modify, '<', '/data/myuser/.mycontent/mytest.xml' ) or die $!; 
open ( my $output, '>', '/data/myuser/.mycontent/mytest.xml.new' ) or die $!; 

select $output; 
while ( <$modify> ) { 
   if ( $. == 32 ) { print <$insert>; }; 
   print; 
}
```

This should do the trick - if you're after a one liner, then it can be condensed down to:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 'BEGIN { open ( $insert, "<", shift ) } if ( $. == 32 ) { print <$insert> }' ~/tmp/test.xml /data/myuser/.mycontent/mytest.xml
```

Note `$.` is `perl` for "current line number". You can apply a different sort of conditional if you prefer. Like whether a regex matches (which might be more appropriate, given config files tend to get lines inserted into them).

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

If you want to insert file1.xml in file2.xml at line 35 with a leading newline:

```
sed -e '34{p;g;r file1.xml' -e '}' file2.xml
```

If you want to edit file2.xml "in place" add sed's option `-i`.

Comment: this worked great for me but what if I don't want the leading new line?

Comment: @MichaelTunnell: `sed -e 34{r file1.xml' -e '}' file2.xml`

Comment: Yep, that was it. I removed p;g; and added -i to the parameters and it works great. Thank you so much for the help and the incredibly fast response! :D

Comment: @MichaelTunnell: I've reduced it to the essential part: `sed '34r file1.xml file2.xml`

Comment: that is essentially what I ended with, thank you for clarifying so I could confirm what I put was correct!

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the problem with you're attempting to do. It looks like you maybe want to insert your `r`ead file on an input cue. You say line 35, but if you do `sed 35r\ file` that will be appended to `35`. It's hard to watch input for a cue *before* which you want to write output if you don't secure a lookahead. For example:

```sh
sed -e'$!N;/\n<Location "\/employee1">/r /tmp/file1' \
    -eP\;D </tmp/file2 | tail -n30
```

---

Now that scans input for the *`<Location /employee1>`* and inserts the content of `file1` immediately before it once found.

---

```
DAVMinTimeout 5000
LimitXMLRequestBody 0

# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.

## I need to add new tags here ##
<Location "/mylocation">
    first Address
    second Address

    Mylocation "XX/XX/XX/XX"
    Myphone "XXXXXXX"
</Location>
<Location "/employee1">
    first Address
    second Address

    Mylocation "XX/XX/XX/XX"
    Myphone "XXXXXXX"
</Location>

<Location "/employee2">
    first Address
    second Address

    Mylocation "XX/XX/XX/XX"
    Myphone "XXXXXXX"
</Location>
## more tags same as above
## then manager comment
```